How to verify AWS SigV4 signing?
I can generate a v4a signature using AWS for Multi Region Access Point to get an S3 Object.

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from enum import Enum
from typing import List, Optional, Tuple, TypedDict, Union, Dict
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import urllib.parse

from aiobotocore.client import AioBaseClient
from botocore import awsrequest  # type: ignore
from botocore.credentials import Credentials  # type: ignore
from botocore.crt.auth import CrtS3SigV4AsymQueryAuth  # type: ignore
class S3Creds(TypedDict):
    """S3 creds."""

    aws_access_key_id: str
    aws_secret_access_key: str
    aws_session_token: Optional[str]

class MRAPSigner(AWSStorageResourceSigner):
    """AWS MRAP Signer."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        endpoint: str,
        creds: S3Creds,
    ) -> None:
        """Initialize MRAPSigner."""
        self._region = "*"
        self._endpoint = endpoint
        self._creds = Credentials(
            access_key=creds["aws_access_key_id"],
            secret_key=creds["aws_secret_access_key"],
            token=creds["aws_session_token"],
        )
        self._s3_sig_v4_asym_query_auth = CrtS3SigV4AsymQueryAuth(
            self._creds,
            "s3",
            self._region,
        )

    def generate_presigned_url(
        self,
        method: S3Method,
        item: str,
        file_type: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> str:
        """Generate presigned url.

        Known Issue:
            - This function should be called not too late \
                (like several minutes) after the creation of the signer.
        """
        aws_request_config: Dict[str, Union[str, Dict]] = {
            "method": method.value,
            "url": self._endpoint + "/" + item,
        }
        if method == S3Method.PUT and file_type:
            headers: Dict[str, str] = {}
            headers["content-type"] = file_type
            aws_request_config["headers"] = headers
        asymmetric_query_request = awsrequest.AWSRequest(**aws_request_config)
        self._s3_sig_v4_asym_query_auth.add_auth(asymmetric_query_request)
        prepared_asymmetric_query = asymmetric_query_request.prepare()
        return prepared_asymmetric_query.url


I want to verify the authenticity of the URL without opening the generated URL, preferably by verifying the signature. Can you please help me with it?
I tried reading the AWS Documentation

Auth using Query String
Auth using HTTP Headers


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113611/is-it-possible-to-validate-a-aws-v4-signature and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241819/how-does-aws-verify-signed-requests

@jarmod That one is for symmetrical ones.

Sorry, you're right that those links aren't useful for sigv4a (sigv4 asymmetric). I don't know how you'd do what you want (or why you'd want to do it) but in this scenario where you want to validate a sigv4a URL, do you have either the public key or private key in hand?
